# Is there a way to completely cancel earlier applications?

Tags: prior-art, patent-applications, pct, novelty, priority

I am looking to use my UK-B application below to file a new PCT-B so that I do not have to prove novelty and inventiveness over the PCT1.

```
1)  UK-A filed on 05/19 now withdrawn without being published
2)  PCT-A filed on 05/20 claiming priority from UK-A
3)  UK-B filed on 06/20
4)  PCT-A published on 07/20
```

Is there really a way to do that?

I have been told that even if I withdraw my PCT-A priority claim over UK-A and even if I abandon my PCT-A and even if I claim priority for my PCT-B over my UK-B, I will still have to prove novelty and inventiveness over the PCT-A, but I do not really understand it.

Can anyone advise please?

PS: I am interested in EU and US mainly.

Comment: We would need to know whether any matter disclosed in UK-B is disclosed in UK-A or PCT-A, and whether you are seeking protection for it or not. UK-A is probably public even if you withdrew it, if you validly claimed its priority in PCT-A and furnished the certified copy of UK-A, then UK-A is available in the public file of PCT-A (you can take a look yourself at PatentScope).

Comment: @theEuropeist thanks, yes UK-B contains matter that is contained in UK-A and PCT-A. I am seeking protection for both the new UK-B content and the UK-A/PCT-A content. The problem is that with UK-B, I want to claim a broader concept than UK-A/PCT-A, that's why I wanted to proceed with the UK-B as a single patent instead of a combination of UK-B and UK-A/PCT-A. I am worried that UK-A/PCT-A will restrict my ability to broaden the concept with UK-B as I will have to prove novelty and inventiveness. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Filing another application (say PA) now and claiming priority from UK-B will result in the following effective dates:

- (1) For PA's matter disclosed in UK-B for the first time: the filing date of UK-B
- (2) For PA's matter already disclosed in any of UK-A and PCT-A: the filing date of PA

This means that matter (2) has the problem of UK-A and PCT-A disclosures, which are prior art for PA, whereas matter (1) does not have that problem.

If you were to enter into the European regional phase from PCT-A (say EP-A) and PA is or becomes a European patent application (say EP-B) at some point in time, whatever you claim in EP-B has to be novel over UK-A/PCT-A, so it must be novel over matter (2). This is because, at the EPO, EP-A is comprised in the state of the art but for the novelty requirement only (cf. [Art.54(3) EPC](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2016/e/ar54.html)). Not sure if a similar provision exists in the US.